# WSO2 Identity Server 5.11 - Account recovery / set-password API not working as expected

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have an unexpected behavior when I try to reset the **first password** (password set during registration) using the account recovery REST API (wso2 identity server version 5.11).

It only happens when I attempt to reset the password for the **first time**. It works as expected from the second attempt and forward.

Steps to reproduice:

- Configure password history validation :

```
[identity_mgt.password_policy]
enable_password_history=true
no_of_previous_passwords_to_disallow=10
```

- Send password recovery confirmation over Email:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"username": "[USERNAME]","realm": "[USER STORE NAME]","tenant-domain":"[TENANT DOMAIN NAME]"},"properties": []}' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/recover-password?type=email&notify=true"
```

- Invoke the set-password API with the confirmation key and the same password used during registration:

```
url -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key": "[CONFIRMATION KEY]", "password": "[NEW PASSWORD]","properties": []}' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/set-password"
```

- The response I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2023 14:33:41 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
```

- The expected behavior:

```
< HTTP/1.1 412 
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
/v0.9; Secure; HttpOnly
< Date: Thu, 30 Nov 2023 14:34:50 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: 
< 
* Connection #1 to host localhost left intact
{"code":"22001","message":"This password has been used in recent history. Please choose a different password","description":"This password has been used in recent history. Please choose a different password","key":"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
```

Is the password set at registration included in password history ?

Comment: How did you register the user? admin registered the user or self signed up the user? Can you share the API you used to register the user as well? I couldn't reproduce the issue in 5.11.0 even with the user registered by admin/ self signup

Comment: could you please add the exact crul command as well. (add all user attribute you add into the payloas but with dummy values). Are you creating the user with askPassword set to true?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna

sorry for the last comment, I am using Self Sign-Up api (not scim2) to create users : 

request example : 
 
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic <Base64Encoded_username:password>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"username": "<username>","realm": "<user_store>", 
"password": "<password>",
"claims": [{"uri": "<claim_URI>","value": "<claim_value>" },
{"uri": "<claim_URI2>","value": "<claim_value2>"},
{"uri": "<claim_URI3>","value": "<claim_value3>"},
 ] },"properties": []}' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/user/v1.0/me"